# How to use Regex to return a directory from TM_FILEPATH in vscode user snippets?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I am looking for a way to create a user snippet to grab the core directory from a project. Here is the sample path that I am using:

`C:dev/Pseudope/Unreal/Cubicle/Source/CubicleCore/Private`

When creating vscode snippets `${TM_FILEPATH}` will return this path to be used along side a regular expression. I want to be able to use these snippets for different projects that will all have the same structure as the filepath above where the text that I want to apply to the snippet will always be nested between Source and Private|Public. Here is the regex that I have so far:

`(?<=Source\\)(.*)(?=\\Private|Public)`

According to https://regexr.com/ this expression will target the value "CubicleCore" as well as group it into group 1. Unfortunately, there seems to be a disconnect between the regular expression in the browser and how vscode is interpreting it because the result I get is:

`UE_LOG(Log${TM_FILEPATH/(?<=Source\)(.*)(?=\Private|Public)/}, Log, TEXT("Hello");`

When it should be:

`UE_LOG(LogCubicleCore, Log, TEXT("Hello");`

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
"UE_LOG(Log${TM_FILEPATH/.*Source[\\\\\\/]([^\\\\/]+)[\\\\\\/](?:Private|Public).*/$1/}, Log, TEXT(\"Hello\")"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZcJDYr/3).

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `Source`  -  `Source`
- `[\\\/]` - `/` or `\`
- `([^\\\/]+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): any one or more chars other than `\` and `/`
- `[\\\/]` - a `/` or `\` char
- `(?:Private|Public)` - `Private` or `Public` string
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I appreciate the detailed explanation. Not only does this solve my question (I already tested in vscode) but it also provided a deeper understanding of regex thanks!

Comment: @Pseudope I should have mentioned that in the `${TM_FILEPATH/pattern/replacement/flags}` you need to use the repalcement logic (you used a matching one), and you also need to double escape backslashes to form regex escapes, otherwise they are simply ignored if not part of valid string escape sequences.